# Library to perform coordinate system transformations?

Tags: python, numpy, coordinate-systems

Is there a python library which handles coordinate system transformations?
I'm working with numpy meshgrids, but sometimes it's useful to switch the coordinate systems.
Since I don't want to reinvent the wheel, are there any libraries which handle:

- transformations (cartesian, spherical, polar, ...)
- translations
- rotations?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the shapely library:
http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html

Affine transformation: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#affine-transformations

Coordinate transformation: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#other-transformations
Sample code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from functools import partial
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform

point1 = Point(9.0, 50.0)

print (point1)

project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326'),
    pyproj.Proj('epsg:32632'))

point2 = transform(project, point1)
print (point2)
```

You can also use the ogr library. i.e.

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr

source = osr.SpatialReference()
source.ImportFromEPSG(2927)

target = osr.SpatialReference()
target.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt("POINT (1120351.57 741921.42)")
point.Transform(transform)

print (point.ExportToWkt())
```

(from http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html)

Answer (score 4):

Concerning transformation and rotation I found [transformations.py](https://github.com/cgohlke/transformations/)
from Christoph Gohlke very useful.